# Keep source files from collapsing in Chrome developer tools with refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I do a refresh in Chrome with developer tools open, it collapses the Sources tree and I have to navigate down the tree to my source file again. How do I keep my tree open - and even more desirable, keep the current source file active.